# Pivot data in PostgreSQL using two columns for row data

Tags: postgresql, group-by

In PostgreSQL I have a table `country` and a table `property`. One country can have a lot of properties. Each property have a `created_at`. I need count the properties for each country separating by the year and week. Like an example i have that query for one country.

```
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) AS yy, 
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM created_at) AS week, 
  COUNT(id) AS country_1
FROM property 
WHERE id_country = 1
GROUP BY week, yy 
ORDER BY yy, week ASC
```

The result of that is something like this

```
yy  |week|country_1
---------------
2014|1   |5
2014|2   |1154
2014|3   |769
...
```

So, i need a result like this

```
yy  |week|country_1|country_2|country_3
----------------------------------------
2014|1   |5        |56       |543
2014|2   |1154     |1234     |432
2014|3   |769      |123      |432
...
```

Is that possible?, how would be the query?

Comment: Are the `country` values few and known beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution without any extensions:

```
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) AS yy, 
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM created_at) AS week, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN id_country = 1 THEN id ELSE null END) AS country_1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN id_country = 2 THEN id ELSE null END) AS country_2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN id_country = 3 THEN id ELSE null END) AS country_3,
  ...
  COUNT(CASE WHEN id_country = 7 THEN id ELSE null END) AS country_7,
FROM property 
GROUP BY week, yy 
ORDER BY yy, week ASC;
```

And if you are using pg 9.4 or later you could replace

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN id_country = 2 THEN id ELSE null END) AS country_2
```

with

```
COUNT(id) FILTER (WHERE id_country = 2) AS country_2
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with the `crosstab()` function (in the `tablefunc` extension), which pivots your data. Unfortunately that function can pivot only on a single column, so you'll have to fudge your data a bit and then un-fudge it to get the desired result.

First the fudge, instead of producing two columns like this:

```
extract(year from created_at) AS yy, 
extract(week from created_at) AS week
```

you should put them in a single column like so:

```
extract(year from created_at) * 100 + extract(week from created_at) AS yr_wk
```

giving you values like `201401, 201402, 201403` etc. The nice property is that they sort just like separate year and week values  and they are easy to assemble and later disassemble.

Next you run the [`crosstab()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) function:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT extract(year from created_at) * 100 + extract(week from created_at) AS yr_wk,
          id_country, count(id) AS cnt
   FROM property GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 1, 2',
  'SELECT s FROM generate_series(1, 7) s'
  ) AS (yr_wk int, c1 int, c2 int, c3 int, c4 int, c5 int, c6 int, c7 int);
```

where 'c1'-'c7' are the names of your countries.

And then to unfudge the `yr_wk` values you do:

```
SELECT yr_wk / 100 AS yy, yr_wk % 100 AS week, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7
FROM (
  << crosstab query from above >>
) sub
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```